# Using setOnItemClickListener for items in listview

Tags: android, listview

I have got an app that saves audio on sd card. I've created a listview which retrieves the filesnames from the sdcard. I'm trying to set a listener so when the file name is clicked I can launch another intent that plays that file. when I try to set the listener and pass in a new `OnItemClickListener()` eclipse is red underlining it. I understand that I have to implement the `onItemclick()`, this is where I think the intent ought to go.

Code:

```
package com.tecmark;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;

public class SdGetList extends Activity {
    private ListView lv1;
    private String[] lv_arr;
    private ArrayList<String> arr;
        
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.listlayout);
        arr = new ArrayList<String>();

        File sdCardRoot = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        Log.i("root on sd =", ""+ sdCardRoot.getPath());

        for (File f : sdCardRoot.listFiles()) {
            if (f.isFile()){
                String name = f.getName();
                arr.add(name);
                Log.i("arr is empty?******", ""+arr.isEmpty());
            }
            else {
                Log.i("file", " no file");
            }
            Log.i("arr******", ""+arr.size());
        }
        lv_arr = new String[arr.size()];

        for(int i=0 ; i<arr.size();i++) {
            lv_arr[i] = arr.get(i);
        }

        lv1=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.ListView01);
        // By using setAdpater method in listview we an add string array in list.
        lv1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 , lv_arr));
        lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            }
        } );
    }
}
```

Comment: what is Eclipse red underlining?  The OnItemClickListener, or some code you're putting in the onItemClick method that isn't listed here?  Regardless, Eclipse is pretty good about giving you feedback on why it's red-underlining something.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
list.setOnItemClickListener( new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
        Intent i = new Intent(ClassName.this,CourtDetailActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    });
}
```

this is the code is properly working I think you do not import blow Package

```
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
```

put this line to import section of the application

Answer (score 2):

Check class imports in your java file. In Eclipse: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>