# How to implement onClick in a Listview

Tags: android, android-listview, onclick

I guess this is simple.

I want to toast the text in the rows when I click on it. And here is my code:

> public class AndroidSQLite extends Activity {         private SQLiteAdapter
>   mySQLiteAdapter;
>
> ```
> @Override
> public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>     setContentView(R.layout.main);
>     ListView listContent = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.contentlist);
>     mySQLiteAdapter = new SQLiteAdapter(this);
>     mySQLiteAdapter = new SQLiteAdapter(this);
>     mySQLiteAdapter.openToRead();
>
>     Cursor cursor = mySQLiteAdapter.queueAll();
>     startManagingCursor(cursor);
>
>     String[] from = new String[]{SQLiteAdapter.KEY_NOME};
>     int[] to = new int[]{R.id.text};
>
>     SimpleCursorAdapter cursorAdapter =
>      new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.row, cursor, from, to);
>
>     listContent.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);
>
>     mySQLiteAdapter.close();
> }
> ```
>
> }

Thank You!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4993311/925070

Comment: possible duplicate of [using setOnItemClickListener for items in listview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4993026/using-setonitemclicklistener-for-items-in-listview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
listContent.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {

            String item = ...;

            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), item, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 5):

just write down

```
listContent.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View arg1,
                    int position, long id) {

                Log.i("get ItemIDPosition",
                        "" + adapter.getItemIdAtPosition(position));
                Log.i("get ItemATPosition", "" + adapter.getItemAtPosition(position));

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
listContent.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                    long id) {

            }

        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code for Item click

```
listContent.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {

        String text = <Get Your from database is here in this string>;

        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use onitemclick evetn and not onclick.

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(...);

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3)
```

arg2 is the index in the list.