# Usage of onClick

Tags: listview

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
private String[] Numbers = 
    {"1", "2", "3", "4","5",
     "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ListView myList=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);


    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>
    (this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, Numbers);


    myList.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

after this point, I couldn't use `myList.setOnItemClickListener` method that opens new screen in the app.

Comment: Please show some code, where you get stuck.?

Comment: See the first answer on this post to use a listener on your ListView: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4993026/using-setonitemclicklistener-for-items-in-listview

It also shows how to start a new Activity when you click an item on your list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very simple.
What you want to do here is that put a ItemClickListener on ListView.

When a particular Item from ListView gets Clicked take its location and according to that count sum there.

And send that sum through Intent to other activity and display there.

```
 lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            int finalAns=0;
            for (int i = 1; i <= arg2; i++) {
                finalAns+=i;
            }
            Intent inte= new Intent(getApplicationContext(),YoursecondActivity.class);
            inte.putExtra("FinalValue", ""+finalAns);
            startActivity(inte);
        }
    });
```

Comment: That exactly what i am looking for.Can  you please show codes?Also I don't know where to I write function that makes calculation.

Comment: I put the code here in my ans..
And what you do here is that just put your object of ListView in place of **lv**.

Answer (score 0):

use below code to change activity.
    myList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

```
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Second.class);
            startActivity(i);

        }
    });
```